# How to map one object with nested list to list of objects using Automapper or LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

I have models like this:

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Exam
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }​

   ​ public class StudentExam
   ​ {
        ​public int Id { get; set; }
       ​ public int StudentId { get; set; }
       ​ public string ExamId{ get; set; }
   ​ }
```

StudentExam is link table for models Student and Exam. From frontend application, I collect some data in this model:

```
   ​public class StudentExamModel
   ​{
       ​public int StudentId { get; set; }
       ​public List<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
   ​}
```

So, in this StudentExamModel I have for example StudentId = 3 with list of 3 exams with Ids 1, 2 and 3 (names of examps are not important right now). Can I map this StudentExamModel to StudentExam using Automapper, so I have 3 rows inside StudentExam like this:

```
    ​StudentId ExamId
   ​  3         1
   ​  3         2
   ​  3         3
```

?

Comment: Show us the code without AM, just with LINQ.

Comment: I don't have LINQ code... I can update the question, how to do it using AM or LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this profile?

```
public class MyMapping : Profile
{
    public MyMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<StudentExamModel, IReadOnlyList<StudentExam>>()
            .ConvertUsing(model => model.Exams
                                .Select(exam => new StudentExam { StudentId = exam.Id, ExamId = exam.Id.ToString() })
                                .ToList());
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(conf => conf.AddProfile<MyMapping>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var source = new StudentExamModel
{
    StudentId = 3,
    Exams = new List<Exam>
    {
        new Exam { Id = 1 },
        new Exam { Id = 2 },
        new Exam { Id = 3 },
    }
};

var dest = mapper.Map<IReadOnlyList<StudentExam>>(source);

foreach (var item in dest)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.StudentId} - {item.ExamId}");
}
```

Here is the [corresponding fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SpwyrZ). And if you already had provided such an fiddle where just the mapping itself was missing, it had been much easier to help you. ;-)

Comment: It is working! Thank you! The only change I made is StudentId = model.StudentId instead of StudentId = exam.Id.  You can update this, so other peopse can see. Great job!